# Hitch in Bootstrap 4 carousel in Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, microsoft-edge

## Bootstrap 4.1.x Carousel

The new Bootstrap 4.1.x carousel can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/

> NOTE: This issue only exists in Edge

#### Description

If you are in the new Microsoft Edge browser, it's very subtle, but I have noticed that there is a small *hitch* at the end of the animation when the image is finished sliding.

To be specific: When the animation is finished, the image "flashes" a distance (sometimes 5% of the width of the slide, sometimes 5 pixels, sometimes 10 pixels) to the right from where it "lands," subsequently "sliding" back to where it "landed."

It doesn't happen all the time. I assume it just happens at random, but it's something that has grown to annoy me.

If anyone is able to tell me why there is a hitch at the end of the animation, I would be more than pleased to fix it on my new website.

I'm using a CDN. Here is a list of the uncompressed versions of my dependencies and their source code, respectively:

### JS

- https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js
- http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.js
- https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.js

### CSS

- https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css
- https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

#### TLDR:

If you happen to know how to get rid of the little hitch on the Bootstrap 4 Carousel animation in Edge, I would love to know how to get rid of it.

Comment: I don't see it, Where is your html for your carousel? Edit your question and add it in

Comment: @mlegg Refer to the documentation for an example. It's very subtle, and it only happens maybe once out of every 3 or 4 times that the carousel "slides." Are you using Microsoft Edge? It only happens in Edge.